# IIS 8 - why WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest is null in CheckAccessCore method of ServiceAuthorizationManager class

Tags: wcf, iis-8, operationcontext

WCF 4.5

I have created and successfully implemented CustomAuthorizationManager which inherits ServiceAuthorizationManager class and overrides its CheckAccessCore method in the past on the IIS7.

Now, I have the following problem on IIS 8:

"WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest is null".

Configration file correctly points to CustomAuthorizationManager class and invokes CheckAccessCore method but operationContext is suddenly null although on IIS 7 it works just fine.

Please help

Comment: WebOpeationContext.Current is also null

Comment: The solution is rather simple. Just use IP address instead of localhost when calling the service.